# How do I specify language literals in hsparql?

Tags: haskell, rdf, sparql

If the raw SPARQL is `rdfs:label "D (programming language)"@en`, what would the hsparql syntax be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of the hsparql DSL that you are having trouble with. A `simpleSelectWithLiteral' function has been added as an example:
https://github.com/robstewart57/hsparql/blob/master/tests/DBPedia.hs#L51

Does this solve your problem?

Comment: Huh, so my guess based off the DSL definition was correct (bar my error with the quotes), strange that @mcandre said using a tuple like that didn't compile.  Does the DSL restrict where in a triple pattern literals can be used?  SPARQL only allows them in the subject/object position so I wonder if he tried to use one in the predicate position hence still a compiler error

Comment: @RobV If you take a look at the instances for TermLike, it might make more sense, perhaps: https://github.com/robstewart57/hsparql/blob/master/Database/HSparql/QueryGenerator.hs#L227 . On line 252, you will see how the tuple is permitted, which is where the RDFLiteralLang constructor is used.

Comment: @RobStewart Thanks for adding the example! I don't know what I was doing wrong with my tuple, probably just a spelling error. Works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [DSL definition](https://github.com/robstewart57/hsparql/blob/master/Database/HSparql/QueryGenerator.hs) (line 251) on the [HSparql Github page](https://github.com/robstewart57/hsparql) it looks like the following DSL rule applies:

```
instance TermLike ([Char], [Char]) where
  varOrTerm (s, lang') = Term . RDFLiteralTerm $ RDFLiteralLang s lang'
```

It's been far too long since I wrote any Haskell so I'm not 100% certain what that translates to into a term but I assume it means use a tuple of two strings:

```
("value", "en")
```

Comment: Single quotes denote a character: `'x'`, so you mean `("value", "en")`. I've tried using a tuple in hsparql, and it doesn't compile.

Comment: Thanks, I did say it's been a while since I wrote any Haskell!